# How to assign a Powershell function as an argument to a different function's parameter

Tags: powershell, scripting

So, I have two functions: 
**First function:**

```
function FunctionExecutor
{
    param
    (
        $function
    )
}
```

**Second function is this:**

```
function StartSSHsession
{   
    Write-Host "Hi"
}
```

Question: How do I execute the StartSSHSession by passing it into FunctionExecuter?

This is executing nothing.

```
FunctionExecutor -function: StartSSHsession
```

Comment: What are you seeking to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I'd like to parameterize a function that sends email, I'd like to use the send email function in another function with dynamic parameters.

Comment: What you want is already built into PowerShell. It's called [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to [dot-source](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html):

```
function FunctionExecutor
{
    param
    (
        $function
    )
    . $function
}
```

Bear in mind you're only passing in the name.

---

An example using an additional [**`Switch`**](https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html) parameter and using [$PSBoundParameters](https://ss64.com/ps/psboundparameters.html) automatic variable:

```
function StartSSHsession
{   
    param(
        [switch]$useEmail
    )
    if($useEmail){
        Write-Host "Use Email"
    }else{
        Write-Host "Hi"
    }
}

function FunctionExecutor
{
    param
    (
        [switch]$useEmail,
        $function
    )
    . $function @PSBoundParameters
}
```

Comment: Great, so when I ran FunctionExecutor -function StartSSHsession it worked. Can I have multiple parameters in FunctionExecutor? For example? param
    (
        $function,
        [Bool] useEmail
    )

Comment: @Hashim77 It's doable - see edit. I'd recommend `[switch]` over `[bool]` unless you have a specific reason for using it. Also, unless the `FunctionExecutor` is going to run a load of similar functions that have similar parameters it's worth considering another approach. E.g. have the `StartSSHSession` function and other functions [in a module that you import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell's way of passing *code* around is by way of *script blocks*** (instances of type `[scriptblock]`, which you can literally ***create* and pass as `{ ... }`** and ***execute* with  `&`**, the call operator.

Therefore, define your function as follows:

```
function CodeExecutor
{
    # Make the function an *advanced* function, which prevents attempts to
    # use undeclared parameters.
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param
    (
        # Define the piece of functionality to accept as a [scriptblock]
        [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
    )

    # Invoke the script block with `&`
    & $ScriptBlock
}
```

Now, *after* defining `StartSSHsession`...

```
function StartSSHsession {
   param(
     $Foo
   )
   Write-Host "Hi: $Foo"
}
```

... you can pass it to `CodeExecutor` as follows, using a script block *with arguments*:

```
CodeExecutor -ScriptBlock { StartSSHsession Bar }
```

... which yields:

```
Hi: Bar
```

Alternatively, you could pass the arguments to pass to the script block separately, as arguments to `CodeExecutor` directly, which could then pass it on as `& $ScriptBlock ...`

---

As for **what you tried**:

> This is executing nothing.
>   `FunctionExecutor -function: StartSSHsession`

You're not showing us what you're doing with parameter `$Function` inside `FunctionExecutor`, but, in the absence of explicit *typing* of the parameter, the specific token passed - `StartSSHsession` - is interpreted as a *string* `[System.String]`.